# Node-RED - Variable Set Not Setting

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

The Code Overall is to act as a switch making it saying if its 'hit'. The switch activates once until needing to reset. However, the hitobject or reset isn't restarting thus activating hit repeatedly if payload is true.

How can I fix it so it requires a false in payload to be active again

```js
var hitobject = context.get("hitojbect") || true;

if (msg.payload == true && hitobject == true) {
  hitobject = false;
  context.set("hitobject", hitobject);
  console.log("Hit");
} else if (msg.payload == false && hitobject == false) {
  hitobject = true;
  context.set("hitobject", hitobject);
  console.log("Not Hit");
}

return;
```

I tried:

- different datatypes to bool & number but hasn't changed at all
- inserting an only 1 output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line will always evaluate to `true`

```
var hitobject = context.get("hitojbect") || true;
```

Because if you store `false` it will always trip the or and set the value to `true`.

Try

```
var hitobject = context.get("hitojbect")
if (hitobject === undefined) {
  hitobject = true
}
```